# Order number of highlight element

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

i need to get number of order highlighted element (by javascript, jquery):

```
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li class="highlight">C</li>
<li>D</li>
```

so, in this case i want to get number 3 into my variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Index](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
var highlighted = $('li').index($('.highlight'));
```

Note: since index will be 0 based, this will return 2.  If you need 3 instead, just add 1.

Answer (score 0):

Or plain js:

```
var index;
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (var i = 1; i < lis.length; i++) {
            if (lis[i].className == "highlight") {
                alert("this index: " + i);
                index = i; 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')){
    alert(index);
  };
});
```

Note: since index will be 0 based, this will return 2. If you need 3 instead, just add 1 to index.

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')){
        alert(index+1 + ': '+ $(this).text());
      };
    });
```